# License selection when submitting a paper and uploading it to arxiv at the same time

Tags: publications, journals, arxiv, online-publication

I am a PhD candidate and I'm going to submit a paper to a journal (let's say to one of top-10 journals related to my topic) and at the same time I'd like to upload that paper to arxiv. 
I know that the arxiv license strongly depends
on the journal requirements, but is there any general guideline for license selection? The second question is that will I be able to submit the paper to the second scientific journal If the paper

- is rejected from the first one;
- is uploaded to arxiv

and

- the second journal prohibits the arxiv license  that was selected before?

Comment: Check the journals license. Most of top journals have a license section for preprints. In fact a lot of them ask you to link your preprint at submission process.